# Creating a subcategory for Category in yii

Tags: php, yii

I have certain products..now i want to create a subcategory for those product..i created a table for subcategory with category as foreign key...[image]

Please anybody help me to achieve this

Comment: Can you show your models? As I understand, each product have one category and each category can have many subcategories? Is it right?

Comment: Yes,for example if I enter a product is sherlock Holmes category = Books, sub category = fiction

Comment: use GII like in example below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a model `SubCategory` like you did for `Category`, but with this relation:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'category' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Category', 'category_id'),
    );
}
```

In `Category` you can add this relation:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'subCategories' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'SubCategory', 'category_id'),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to do it is to go to YOURDOMAIN/index.php/gii
And you create your models and the relations using the interface.
Thanks